# how to add a number as well as format change to column value and print it in 3rd column

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I have these two columns with header:

```
CHR BP
1   78901
```

I need to add a character to the first column numbers (chr). I also need to make a third column in which one score being added to the second column value (x to x+1) in this way:

```
CHR BP new-column 
chr1  78901  78902
```

appreciate your helps

Answer (score 2):

An Awk solution

```bash
echo -e 'CHR BP\n1   78901' | awk -v FIRST_COL_PREFIX="chr" -v THIRD_COL_NAME="new-colum" 'NR == 1 {print $0, THIRD_COL_NAME; next} {print FIRST_COL_PREFIX $1, $2, $2 + 1}'
```

Output:

```
CHR BP new-colum
chr1 78901 78902
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{$(NF+1)=NR>1?$2+1:"new-column";if (NR>1) $1= "chr"$1}1' input_file
CHR BP new-column
chr1 78901 78902
```

Comment: thank you very much...this line works

Comment: Great!. Please check this
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers @motor30